# How can I open a file marked as 'Resource' from another assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, resources

I am trying to create a plug-in system, where I load assemblies that are located in a specific folder dynamically. One of the things I need to do is load files marked as 'resource' in the plug-in assembly.

One of my use cases is trying to obtain stored icons. What I have right now is this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("ThePlugin.dll");
Uri fullPath = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + assembly.GetName().Name + ";component/" + path.TrimStart('/'), UriKind.Absolute);
ImageSource image = new BitmapImage(fullPath);
```

I tried setting the build action of image file in the plugin to 'Resource', 'Content', I tried enabling 'Copy to output directory', but so far none these methods worked. I always get an exception that the image file could not be found.

However, using the above method works for the host assembly (`assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`)

I suspect that because I didn't reference the plugin assembly in the host project, it can't resolve the Uri.

What am I doing wrong?

I am also considering implementing an alternative method of obtaining the resource: have an interface that the plugin can implement, and then use that interface to obtain resources.

Comment: This approach works for me when the image file contained in the plugin assembly is marked as `Resource`, even without referencing the plugin assembly. Except that `Assembly.LoadFile` needs an absolute path.

Comment: I ended up doing things differently: I store the resource files in the resx file, instead of the project. This way I can load them just fine with a `ResourceManager`.